# Given a differentiable and uniformly continuous function, show its derivative converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f is differentiable on the real number line and f' is uniformly continuous, I need to show that

$g_n(x)=n[f(x+1/n)-f(x)]$

Converges uniformly to f'

Comment: Maybe you mean $g_n(x)=n\left(f\left(x+\frac1n\right)-f(x)\right)$ ?

Comment: That's right, what does my statement read as? Is it the 1/n?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** fix any $x$, consider
$$
\lvert g_n(x)-f'(x)\rvert
$$
and use the Mean Value Theorem to get something of the form
$$
\lvert g_n(x)-f'(x)\rvert = \lvert f'(c_x)-f'(x)\rvert.
$$
where $c_x$ is "close to $x$." Now, time to use the assumption that $f'$ is uniformly continuous to upper bound this in a way which does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I read this as $f$ is UC and $f$ is differentiable, not $f'$ is UC.

Comment: Quoting the OP's question: "Suppose f is differentiable on the real number line and f' is uniformly continuous" @MarkViola

Comment: Sorry, I had probably just edited the question

Comment: (And indeed,if the assumption is not on $f'$, then $f'$ need not even be continuous -- I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head, but I'd be very surprised if the result held under the assumption $f$ UC and differentiable, nothing known on $f'$)

Comment: I don't see how the mean value theorem implies the existence of such a cx though

Comment: @Alosapien Fix $x$. Applying the [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), we get that there exists $c_x\in(x,x+\frac{1}{n})$ such that $$g_n(x) = \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{x+\frac{1}{n}-x}=f'(c_x).$$ (Technically, I should have written $c_{x,n}$ to be absolutely accurate, as it depends on both $n$ and $x$.)

Comment: @Clementc. This is a case in which the title doesn't quite match with the question in the main body.  And without having $f'$ UC, I doubt that $f_n'$ converges uniformly.

Comment: @MarkViola (regarding the last part: yes, I agree -- cf. my comment.)

Comment: @Alosapien Let me know if the above cleared your confusion.

Comment: took me a while, but I understand know. you are using the mean value theorem on x+1/n and the limit of x+1/n->x. this pretty much solves it I believe

Comment: That's the gist of it.